# how to add my own class to ratchat server

Tags: php, class, ratchet

I am using ratchet to create websocket server but i have a problem....
how to write my own classes and use them into this....

PHP :

```
    <?php
    namespace MyApp;
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

    define ("ABSPATH" , "D:/MyProject/server/bin/");
    require_once ABSPATH."config.php";

    require_once ABSPATH."classes/clients.php";// <--- i required this file that
//it contain clients class 
//but when i want to use it i get error that this class notfound

    class Poker implements MessageComponentInterface {
        protected $clients;

        public function __construct(){   
            $this->clients = array();
        }
        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

            $client = new clients($conn);//here i get error
            array_push($this->clients,$client);

        }
        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

    }
        public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        }
        public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {

        }
    }
```

i required the class file

```
require_once ABSPATH."classes\clients.php";
```

but in this line i get error

```
$client = new clients($conn);// ERROR CLASS NOT FOUND
```

ERROR :

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\clients' not found in D:\MyProject\server\src\MyAp
p\Poker.php on line 18
```

Comment: Well does a class called clients exist?

Comment: according to your error, I guess your include path is wrong.

Comment: no if i add some echo in the include path it show the echo message but only i can not use the class @FisherMartyn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the current file is in a namespace, but I assume your file with the clients class is not?

Try adding

```
    namespace MyApp;
```

to clients.php, if you then want to create a new dedicated namespace you will then have to `use` it like the two lines in your current file